# How to check if a variable has the correct type of Map when key and value are class types?

Tags: typescript

I have defined a `type` which contains a property of `Map<SomeClass, SomeOtherClass>` and I want to validate if the incoming parameter is of that exact type.

The only solution I have so far is to write a helper function which first checks if the parameter is an instance of `Map` and then extract the `key` and `value` and check both if they are instances of `SomeClass`/`SomeOtherClass`.

However this obviously fails when the incoming parameter is the correct type but empty, which it shouldn't. Of course I can check in the helper function if the `Map` is empty but then is succeeds with every `Map` no matter what types `key` and `value` is.

```
  type myType {
  index: Map<SomeClass,SomeOtherClass>
}
function validate(data:myType):void{

  if(!data?.index || !isIndexType(data.index))
  throw new Error('not valid');
}
function isIndexType(
  obj: unknown
): obj is Map<SomeClass, SomeOtherClass> {
  if (!(obj instanceof Map)) {
    return false;
  }

  const [key, value] = obj.entries().next().value;

  return key instanceof SomeClass && value instanceof SomeOtherClass;
}
```

How can I check if the `data.index` has the correct type even if it's empty?

The reason why I want to do this, is that a specific value object is constructed correctly and if not a proper exception is being thrown.

```
class myValueObject{
  
  readonly value: myValue;
  constructor(data: myType) {
    validate(data);
    this.value = data;
    
  }
}
```

`myType` can have multiple props and I want to validate each of them also by its type to get a proper error if there is something wrong.
And you could always create an instance of `myValueObject` and pass a parameter with `any` in.

Comment: Please give a [mre], what you've posted isn't valid TypeScript. If the value's empty, why consider it invalid at all?

Comment: "*Of course I can check in the helper function if the Map is empty but then is succeeds with every Map no matter what types key and value is.*" types [do not exist at runtime](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure). So, a map is a map. Not "a map for Foo keys" or "a map for Bar values". An empty map can have anything in it. So it's correct that an empty map will also be able to have `SomeClass` as keys and `SomeOtherClass` as values.

Comment: so in other words, its not possible

Comment: Well not really. But also shouldn't be needed, either. If you have your typings correct then the maps you pass around should have the matching types. You shouldn't really be in a situation where at runtime you have to figure out what a map should contain. It's not quite clear what issue you're solving but seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDeVRm) meet your needs?  You need to check *every* entry (what if the second entry has a different key/value type?); and using `every` will naturally succeed if the map is empty.   If that works for you I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz OP also seems to want to verify an empty map. Which cannot really be done at runtime. Essentially, OP seems to want to verify if a map is a map of some generic parameters, however, at runtime and that should somehow happen regardless of any elements that are in the map.

Comment: @VLAZ An empty map is trivially a `Map<K, V>` for any `K` and `V` you want.  Are you worried about mutation or something?  Presumably the check is at a point in time.  How are what you saying different for whether `[]` is a `string[]`?

Comment: @jcalz The only reason to be worried is if you go `foo = new Map<string, string>(); addNumberKeyAndNumberValueToMap(foo)`. Which will then violate the contract. I assume that's what OP is trying to avoid. Otherwise the question makes no sense. However, then "how do I verify an empty map is of the correct generic type at runtime" is the wrong question to ask instead of trying to to avoid this situation to begin with.

Comment: I think the OP must just be confused about empty maps being an issue; unless someone *else* is going to modify the map after the check, it would be perverse to verify that it's valid and then do invalid things with it.  I will wait until the OP replies to see if they can demonstrate a case where an empty map should actually be rejected.

Comment: Well I can always pass `any` as a parameter, doesn't it make sense then to validate this?

Comment: ^ I don't understand the question. Could you rephrase?

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: I still don't see why you'd need that. If `myType` is compatible with `myValue`, then it should work without requiring runtime validation. And you also shouldn't be being passed an argument that is incompatible with `myType`. Moreover, is it even expected that `data` be updated *outside* the instance it is passed in? Because that's the only real reason to try and code defensively for potential data type mismatch. But if that was the case, you are not coding defensively *enough*. What is *the real* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you're soooooo concerned about empty maps, consider extending `Map` and requiring that extended class instead... https://tsplay.dev/m0YVnW

Comment: @VLAZ well since it is possible to create an instance of `myValueObject` and pass in anything as long its typed ad `any` I just want to validate it. You think this is too much?

Comment: I suggest you don't use `any`? Like the entire point of it is that it's an escape hatch from the type system. And if you're going to be subverting the type system *anyway*, it's a poor choice to try and bandage that at runtime. Either use the type system to do what it's meant to do - you know *verify types*, or don't. Even in pure JS setting boundaries and sticking to contracts is the usual way to handle these situations. A variable can be *anything* but it's madness to try and verify absolutely every parameter everywhere in the entire application.

Comment: @zlZimon I don't think we're communicating effectively.  It would help if you could demonstrate *with code* a situation in which an empty map should be *rejected* by `isIndexType()`... or any situation in which [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDeVRm) does the wrong thing.

Comment: @jcalz the mistake I was made was thinking that there is a difference between `Map<classA,classB>()` and `Map<classC,classD>()` at runtime which was clarified by @VLAZ in the second comment. The rest of the discussion was just about the sense of checking the type as I did, as I know understand is not needed as much as I thought.